# finding Length of a diagonal

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given Quadrilateral ABCD in such that $AB<BC<CD$ creating increasing arithmetic progression with sum of $27$ cm.

$\measuredangle BCD=60^{0}$. the diagonal $BD=\sqrt{133}$ cm, and it divided $\measuredangle ABC$ such that:

$\measuredangle CBD=2\measuredangle DBA $ .  compute the length of diagonal $AC$.

This is a bit strange because computing by law of sines or law of cosines will give different number of solutions and i can't really prove that one of the solutions is disqualified.

If we look at triangle $BCD$: $\frac{\sqrt{133}}{sin60^{0}}=\frac{9}{sin\measuredangle BDC}$
so $\measuredangle BDC=42.5^{0}$ and $\measuredangle DBC=77.48^{0}$

But if i compute: $\frac{\sqrt{133}}{sin60^{0}}=\frac{13}{sin\measuredangle DBC}$  so  $\measuredangle DBC=77.48^{0}$ or $102.51^{0}$

Comment: It will help on this end if you show what you found, so someone here can tell you which one of your solutions worked right or went wrong...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner - did it right now.

Comment: i would appreciate if someone can explain why i should think from the start to rule out one of the solution if i use law of sine such that angle $DBC=77.48^{0} or 102.51^{0}$? it fits the problem and i don't think that i need to compute again using law of sine differently just to rule out the other angle. in addition: is there any restriction of using law of cosine? maybe the 2 answers would fit aand then cosine wouldn't get me there.

Comment: You say the perimeter is 27?  But in your 2nd solution you seem to identify length(CD) = 13.  Is that right?  Where did that 13 come from?

Comment: The 13 comes from applying the Law of Cosines and the arithmetic sequence requirement that CD have length $9 + d$ to get the diagonal BD to have length $\sqrt{133}$.

Comment: @getter Remember that the Law of Sines applied to your problem _also_ requires that $\frac{\sin 60^{\circ}}{\sqrt{133}} = \frac{\text{angle BDC}}{9}$ .  For angle $DBC = 77.48^{\circ}$, the angles of triangle $BCD$ will sum to $180^{\circ}$; for $DBC = 102.51^{\circ}$ [the supplementary value], they won't...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner - i now that. that's the first approach that i worte. with the second one i find truble to understand why it works well unless i consider the first approach and then it fails.

Comment: @getter: To repeat, use the Law of Cosines. Gets you the answer, doesn't get you to chase a non-answer.

Comment: Then you've already answered your own question, since the geometric requirements permit only one consistent solution. Judgements sometimes must be made about results from the Law of Sines alone; results from the Law of Cosines are unambiguous.

Comment: @getter, Is AB+BC+CD=27?  And no constraint on DA?  I understand you're trying to go through both methods and see the same result, that makes sense, I just think I'm missing some information.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AB=x$, $BC=x+y$, $CD=x+2y$. The sum is $27$, so $x+y=9$.

Now use the Cosine Law. We have $CD=9+y$, and therefore
$$133=(9+y)^2+81-(2)(9)(9+y)(1/2).$$
This simplifies to $y^2+18y-52=(y+13)(y-4)=0$, so $y=4$. Thus our arithmetic progression is $5,9,13$.

Now we can use the Cosine Law again to find the cosine of $\angle CBD$, and then trigonometric identities to find the cosine of $\angle ABC$, and then the Cosine Law to find $AC$. Although exact expressions can be found, they are not particularly attractive. The angle $ABC$ turns out to be approximately $116.22$ degrees.

**Remark:** Using the Sine Law is less efficient: the cosine identifies the angle of a triangle uniquely, but the sine does not.  So using the Sine Law to compute $\angle DBC$ leads to extra work.  There is only one possible answer, since the sides determine the angles.

We can rule out the possibility that $\angle DBC$ is obtuse in various ways. For example, we can compute the sine of $\angle CDB$, the smallest angle, by using the Sine Law. There will be no ambiguity, the angle turns out to be about $42.52^\circ$. Now the remaining angle $DBC$ gets uniquely identified: it is $\approx 180-(60+42.52)$.

Comment: thanks but i didn't get why my other solution is wrong.

Comment: that's one way. how can you explain that if i compute by the other way i get angle DBC $77.48^{0}$ or $102.51^{0}$? in that way i can't see what's wrong. it's strange that i need to solve this question with 2 different ways to get the right answer.

Comment: the question is: why should i thinks that it would be a problem (extra work) if it fits by the sum of angles in a triangle?

Comment: no, im asking why if 2 options fits the sum of angles in a triangle  is should consider checking those solutions with another approach?

Comment: There is only one option here that makes the sum of the angles $180^\circ$, for choosing the obtuse angle will violate the Sine Law for the third angle $CDB$. The system is objecting to the length of the comment string. I will delete most of mine, suggest you do the same.

Comment: In my last sentence in my answer i wrote 2 options for angle DBC. in that way, what's the problem there? they are both makes the sum of angles $180^{0}$. $180^{0}-(60^{0}+77.48^{0})$ or $180^{0}-(60^{0}+102.51^{0})$ in that way, why should i even think of rule one out? and can i rule it out without using again, differently, the law of sine?

Comment: The rest of the Law of Sines equality for triangle $BCD$ rules out the 102.51º solution; see the other comment thread...